# What is the meaning of "reduced schemes of finite type"?

Tags: terminology

What does the following term mean?

> category of geometrically reduced schemes of finite type over some field

(I know what a category and a field is but I cannot translate any of the middle bits)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to consult a text on scheme theory, for instance
Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*. A scheme of finite type
over a field $k$ is one with a finite cover of spectra of
rings of the form $k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]/I$ where $I$ is an ideal.
A reduced scheme is a scheme where for each open set $U$ the ring
of functions defined over $U$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.
It's geometrically reduced if it remains reduced when the base
field is changed to its algebraic closure.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 4):

It is probably worth mentioning that another name for this is the category of abstract (not necessarily separated) algebraic $k$-varieties.

Comment: Doesn't one usually require separatedness for varieties?

Comment: @Akhil: this is often the case, but not always.  To my mind, once you allow non-quasi-projective varieties, you might as well allow non-separated guys as well.  (By the way, some people don't require varieties to be reduced either.)